# Can I create one graph per model in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

The benefit would be that I can store and load individual models using `tf.train.export_meta_graph()` but I'm not sure if this usage is what TensorFlow was designed for. Does it have any negative impacts on parallelism/performance, functionality, etc to use multiple graphs in parallel, as long as I don't want to share data between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea because passing data between models would require fetching from one session, and feeding the Python object back into the other session. Locally, that's unnecessary copy operations, and it's worse in the distributed setting.

There is now `export_scoped_meta_graph()` and `import_scoped_meta_graph()` in `tf.contrib.framework.meta_graph` to save and load parts of a graph and using a single global graph is recommended.